# Impossible to prevent auto panning to a marker when clicking on it (google maps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I use the google maps api v3, gmaps4rails and infobox and I cannot figure out how to remove the event which consist in auto panning the map on a marker as soon as it has been clicked...

The markers are sent from my controller:

```
Gmaps4rails.build_markers(experiences) do |experience, marker|
  marker.lat experience.latitude
  marker.lng experience.longitude
  marker.infowindow render_to_string(partial: "/trip_experiences/infowindow.html.erb", locals: {
    experience: experience,
    trip: trip
   })
  marker.title experience.name
end
```

And my map is built in js and markers are created by calling addMarkers on the handler:

> `handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { builders: { Marker: InfoBoxBuilder} });
>      handler.buildMap({ provider: mapOptions, internal: { id: 'map' } }, function(){
>       $.get(url, function(data) {
>         handler.removeMarkers(markers);
>         markers = handler.addMarkers(data);
>         setCarouselOnInfowindow();
>         handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
>         callback(false)
>       });
>     });`

I have tried so far to  `diasbleAutoPan:true` in the map options, to set the markers to unclickable and then add a listener on click, and done a lot of research but I did not found anything like this... So I guess I am doing something wrong but cannot find what!!
Any help would be so grateful.... many tahnks

Edit : 
As suggested by @apneadiving, I tried to override the infowindow_binding method within the custom builder in order to remove `@markers.panTo` line but the map still auto center on marker when clicking on it....
Here is the code for the custom builder :

> `

```
class @InfoBoxBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker # inherit from base builder
      # override method
      create_infowindow: ->
        return null unless _.isString @args.infowindow
        boxText = document.createElement("div")
        boxText.setAttribute("class", 'infobox-container') #to customize
        boxText.innerHTML = @args.infowindow
        @infowindow = new InfoBox(@infobox(boxText))
      infobox: (boxText)->
        content: boxText
        ,disableAutoPan: true
        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, -40)
        ,alignBottom: true
        ,zIndex: null
        ,disableAutoPan: true
        ,closeBoxURL: ""
        ,boxStyle: {
          width: "280px"
          ,opacity: 1
        }
        ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(100, 1000)
        ,isHidden: false
        ,pane: "floatPane"
        ,enableEventPropagation: false
        infowindow_binding: =>
          @constructor.CURRENT_INFOWINDOW.close() if @_should_close_infowindow()
          @infowindow ?= @create_infowindow()
          return unless @infowindow?
          @infowindow.open( @getServiceObject().getMap(), @getServiceObject())
          @marker.infowindow ?= @infowindow
          @constructor.CURRENT_INFOWINDOW = @infowindow
```

`
Any help would be great.... thank you very much

Comment: I'm not sure where to set it(I'm not familiar with ruby on rails), but you must set the option for the infowindow

Comment: its handled in the builder here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/gmaps/google/builders/marker.coffee#L56  since you have a custom builder, you can override the function and remove this line

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedbacks! I will try to override the method whereas I do not know anything in js/coffee (in the meantime, I pass the data to build the infobox in a json from the controller and create the infobox directly in the view in js... not very optimized...) @apneadiving, thank you very much for your gem, it is pretty straight-forward. Great job!

Comment: Hey Appartement Dupleix, did you get this to work? I was trying to do something similar, and I was able to get it to work by copying the entire file that apneadiving references (marker.coffee) and using that as the infoboxbuilder class, and then I commented out the offending line.

Comment: Hi @kindofgreat, unfortunately I did not achieve to do it following the instructions apneadiving's (which was to override the function)... The autopanning was still working... What has worked, is to create myself the infobox directly in the view... But I will be willing to be updated if you finally cracked this issue :)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to check stackoverflow in awhile! Been busy moving. I followed apneadiving's suggestion and it was fine for me. I put the entire file in a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Apneadiving's suggestion as well and it worked fine for me. I put the following inside assets/javascripts/gmaps4rails-infoxbox.coffee. As you can see, all I did was pull the entire code out from the gem, then commented out the line about panning.

```
class @InfoBoxBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker # inherit from base builder
  @CURRENT_INFOWINDOW: undefined
  @CACHE_STORE: {}

  # args:
  #   lat
  #   lng
  #   infowindow
  #   marker_title
  #   picture
  #     anchor: [x,y]
  #     url
  #     width
  #     height
  #   shadow
  #     anchor: [x,y]
  #     url
  #     width
  #     height
  # provider options:
  #   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=fr#MarkerOptions
  # internal_options
  #   singleInfowindow: true/false
  #   maxRandomDistance: null / int in meters
  constructor: (@args, @provider_options = {}, @internal_options = {})->
    @before_init()
    @create_marker()
    @create_infowindow_on_click()
    @after_init()

  build: ->
    @marker = new(@model_class())(@serviceObject)

  create_marker: ->
    @serviceObject = new(@primitives().marker)(@marker_options())

  create_infowindow: ->
    return null unless _.isString @args.infowindow
    new(@primitives().infowindow)({content: @args.infowindow })

  marker_options: ->
    coords = @_randomized_coordinates()
    base_options =
      title:    @args.marker_title
      position: new(@primitives().latLng)(coords[0], coords[1])
      icon:     @_get_picture('picture')
      shadow:   @_get_picture('shadow')
    _.extend @provider_options, base_options

  create_infowindow_on_click: ->
    @addListener 'click', @infowindow_binding

  infowindow_binding: =>
    @constructor.CURRENT_INFOWINDOW.close() if @_should_close_infowindow()
    # @marker.panTo()
    @infowindow ?= @create_infowindow()

    return unless @infowindow?

    @infowindow.open( @getServiceObject().getMap(), @getServiceObject())
    @marker.infowindow ?= @infowindow
    @constructor.CURRENT_INFOWINDOW = @infowindow

  _get_picture: (picture_name)->
    return null if !_.isObject(@args[picture_name]) || !_.isString(@args[picture_name].url)
    @_create_or_retrieve_image @_picture_args(picture_name)

  _create_or_retrieve_image: (picture_args) ->
    if @constructor.CACHE_STORE[picture_args.url] is undefined
      @constructor.CACHE_STORE[picture_args.url] = new(@primitives().markerImage)(picture_args.url, picture_args.size, picture_args.origin, picture_args.anchor , picture_args.scaledSize)

    @constructor.CACHE_STORE[picture_args.url]

  _picture_args: (picture_name)->
    {
      url:        @args[picture_name].url
      anchor:     @_createImageAnchorPosition @args[picture_name].anchor
      size:       new(@primitives().size)(@args[picture_name].width, @args[picture_name].height)
      scaledSize: null
      origin:     null
    }

  _createImageAnchorPosition : (anchorLocation) ->
    return null unless _.isArray anchorLocation
    new(@primitives().point)(anchorLocation[0], anchorLocation[1])

  _should_close_infowindow: ->
    @internal_options.singleInfowindow and @constructor.CURRENT_INFOWINDOW?

  _randomized_coordinates: ->
    return [@args.lat, @args.lng] unless _.isNumber(@internal_options.maxRandomDistance)

    #gives a value between -1 and 1
    random = -> (Math.random() * 2 - 1)
    dx  = @internal_options.maxRandomDistance * random()
    dy  = @internal_options.maxRandomDistance * random()
    Lat = parseFloat(@args.lat) + (180/Math.PI)*(dy/6378137)
    Lng = parseFloat(@args.lng) + ( 90/Math.PI)*(dx/6378137)/Math.cos(@args.lat)
    return [Lat, Lng]
```