# Titanium: How to prevent Google Maps auto panning to marker when clicking on said marker?

Tags: android, google-maps, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm writing a cross-platform mobile app with Titanium (v5.0.4, sdk 5.1.2GA). The app displays a map with markers for points of interest close to current location. If the user moves the map to a new region, all previously displayed markers are removed and a new set of markers is calculated and displayed, according to the new location. The user can click on a marker, and have an infoWindow appear. Clicking the infoWindow opens a new window for further informations.

This works fine on IOS (with MapKit). However, on Android (with Google Maps), clicking on a marker displays the infoWindow, but also centers the map on the marker, which triggers 'regionchanged' event, which causes my app to remove markers and display a new set. Basically, the user can never click the infoWindow nor reach the new window for further informations.

What I'd like to do: prevent Google Maps from auto panning to a marker when clicking on it.

Alternatively, is there a way to make a distinction between a 'regionchanged' event fired after clicking a marker, and a 'regionchanged' event triggered by the user moving the map? This would allow me to react only on the latter.

I've found this ([Impossible to prevent auto panning to a marker when clicking on it (google maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458649/impossible-to-prevent-auto-panning-to-a-marker-when-clicking-on-it-google-maps)) but this is ruby on rails. Something else I came accross (can't find back the link, though) involved overloading the 'click' event handler or using the disableAutoPan infoWindow option ([Google Maps: How to prevent InfoWindow from shifting the map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488999/google-maps-how-to-prevent-infowindow-from-shifting-the-map)), but this were all for the Javascript API.

So, has someone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. Although it's been a long time since you asked the question, I think the solution is worth noting here.

1. Make the map view respond to both `click` and `regionchanged` events

`<View id="mapView"
      module="ti.map"
      onClick="click"
      onRegionchanged="regionChanged"
      method="createView">
</View>`

2. Use a flag variable that both event listeners have access to.

`var clicked = 0;`

3. `click` event sets the variable.

`var click = function(e) {
      clicked = 1;
      ...
}`

4. Wrap the functionality of `regionchanged` event  with `_.defer(...)`.

`var regionChanged = function(e) {
      _.defer(function(){
        ... (regionchanged code goes here)
      });
}`

5. `regionchanged` code should not execute if the variable is set.

`var regionChanged = function(e) {
      _.defer(function(){
        if (clicked == 0) {
          ... (regionchanged code goes here)
        }
      });
}`

6. Unset the variable at the end of the `regionchanged` code.

`var regionChanged = function(e) {
      _.defer(function(){
        if (clicked == 0) {
          ... (regionchanged code goes here)
        }
        clicked = 0;
      });
}`

Here `defer` somehow makes sure when both events are fired (it seems to) `regionchanged` event comes after the click event. I think that may not always be the case but my tests didn't fail me yet.

And I know I could use boolean for `clicked` :)